# Adding sound when button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I've just started coding. I've made a quiz and I want a sound played when my students click the correct answer, and another sound played when they click an incorrect answer. I've found some posts online but they are not working. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Javascript:

```
function checkAnswer(){
    myAnswer=$('#inputBox').val();
    if(myAnswer.slice(myAnswer.length-1,myAnswer.length)==" "){
        myAnswer=myAnswer.slice(0,myAnswer.length-1);}
    if(currentAnswer==myAnswer){
        score++;
        $('#feedback').append('<img src="tick.png">');
        $('#inputBox').css("background-color","green");
        $('#inputBox').css("color","white");
    }
    else{
        $('#feedback').append('<img src="cross.png">');
        $('#inputBox').css("background-color","red");
        $('#inputBox').css("color","white");
        $('#inputBox').val($('#inputBox').val()+" (ans= "+currentAnswer+")");
    }
    $('#message').append('Press ENTER again to continue');
    $("#inputBox").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#gameArea").focus();
    gamePosition=2;
    if(currentQuestionNumber==numberOfQuestions){gamePosition=3;}
}//checkAnswer
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="mainclock.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gameArea" tabindex="1"></div>
    <div id="mainStage">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I do not see any `audio` element in your HTML/JS...

Comment: Refer [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) or [`HTML5 Audio`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp), I am not a fan of `W3Schools` but it may help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are using **[Jquery](https://jquery.com/)** . so i suggest you to use a Jquery based code to handle this process because of [less codding and so on](http://www.jscripters.com/jquery-disadvantages-and-advantages/) .
 So just copy below code at the bottom of yours and call it when ever you need to hear the sound:

```
  function rightAnswerChosen(){
    var audioFileName="audio.mp3";
    $("body").append("<audio src="+audioFileName+" autoplay=true loop=false/>");
  }
```

Its so simple! **do'nt forget** to put your audio file **in the same directory(folder)** that this page is in **AND** replace it's name with 'audio.mp3'.

to have more functionality you can add [more attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp) (ex:loop-preload-volume...) in Audio tag as you wish .

That's it!

Comment: first of all thank you for your help. But the mp3 file is still not played even when I add the code at the bottom of my quiz or when I add it between  $('#inputBox').css("color","white"); and    }  else{. DId I put it in the wrong place or do I need to add another Jquery in my folder? Thanks

Comment: take a look at http://drax.ir/tmp/myquizPage.htm . i put a sample page to play sounds. you can see descriptions in it's source code.

Comment: also you must put AnswerChosen(true);   after if(currentAnswer==myAnswer){  .and of course AnswerChosen(false); when you get a wrong answer. you can download source code and files in my sample page. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `audio` element in JavaScript and play it when necessary in your application. Below an example of how to initiate an `audio` element dynamically in JS.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'some-audio-file-here.mp3');
// play audio
audioElement.play();
// stop audio
audioElement.stop()
```

More information can be found on at [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).